# "On the other hand" usage in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

> "The criminally poor always face a plethora of problems, but if your a wealthy elite **on the other hand**, then that's a whole different story"

Is it possible to use "on the other hand" in this sentence like this?

Comment: You can use it that way and it is idiomatic, however, using *on the other hand*  is not needed in your sentence.  Saying *The criminally poor face problems but if you're a wealthy elite then that's a whole different story,* means the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The use of "on the other hand" looks legit.

However, you should use "you're" instead of "your".

I am bit confused about about what "criminally poor" might mean.

Comment: Thank you so much! Oh yes I overlooked "you're" and when it comes to "criminally poor", it's just a casual way of saying "very poor" but maybe I should stop using it.